# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to get the data from local list sheets and print it, but I get an error. 
Here is my code:

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import xldate_as_tuple
import datetime


data1 = xlrd.open_workbook(r'D:\\test.xlsx')
table = data1.sheets()[0]

tables = []


def import_excel(excel):
    for test in range(excel.nrows):
        array = [table.cell_value(test, 0), table.cell_value(test, 1),
                 table.cell_value(test, 2), table.cell_value(test, 3),
                 table.cell_value(test, 4)]
        tables.append(array)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import_excel(table)
    for i in tables:
        # pass
        print(i)

num1 = tables[0]
num2 = tables[1]
num3 = tables[2]
num4 = tables[3]
num5 = tables[4]

nu1 = 1
while nu1 < num2:
    print("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d" % (nu1, num2, num3, num4, num5))
    nu1 = nu1 + 1
```

I get:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: nu1 is a int however tables[1] (num2) contains an array formed in your function import_excel, array(column0, column1, column2, column3, columnt4). Can you please some detail on what you are looking to do and I may be able to work a solution for you?

Comment: It is hard to solve the issue completely without know what the data is for each table. The error itself implies that one table has an integer value and the other one has a Dictionary as it's value. You cannot compare an Int and a Dict, try to print the num1 and num2 values and see what they are returning.

Comment: What are you trying to compare? Python is right, you're trying to compare the int and list. Let's look deeper. num1 = 1, while tables is a list which contains another lists ("arrays" - look at the loop in the import_excel function).

Comment: And by the way, I've seen this in your code: r'D:\\test.xlsx' If you do this, you're passing "D:\\test.xlsx" (with two slashes). You can do or "D:\\test.xlsx" (without r), or r"D:\test.xlsx"  Why to use r if you write two slashes anyway? A string with r (a "raw string") contains any escape characters you'll give in the string without changes. Read more about it here: https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string

Comment: @DemianWolf But for whatever reason `xlrd.open_workbook` seems to be forgiving of the double \\. But just try to use the same string with `open` and it will fail, so it is good to point this out to the OP.

Comment: here is test.xlsx data:[2.0, 14.0, 21.0, 22.0, 26.0]
[3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 24.0, 30.0]
[4.0, 11.0, 23.0, 26.0, 30.0]
[4.0, 14.0, 20.0, 28.0, 35.0]

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? Please add the stacktrace as well. If the problem can be reproduced with raw Python data (without xlrd and a required Excel file) it would be much easier for others to help you find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error reported by the above program is:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

This error signifies that the **'comparison operator (<)'** is being used to compare dissimilar types of variables.

The variable on the left is an integer, but the variable on the right is an array (list).

**How to fix the error?**

The error can be fixed by making these 2 changes:

1. Update the **condition in while loop** to compare **nu1** with specific element of
   the array (**nu2[i]**).
2. Update the **print** statement to print specific elements of the arrays

**Here is an example of working code:**

```
# File name:  demo.py

import xlrd
from xlrd import xldate_as_tuple
import datetime


data1 = xlrd.open_workbook(r'D:\\test.xlsx')
table = data1.sheets()[0]

tables = []


def import_excel(excel):
    for test in range(excel.nrows):
        array = [
                  table.cell_value(test, 0), 
                  table.cell_value(test, 1),
                  table.cell_value(test, 2), 
                  table.cell_value(test, 3),
                  table.cell_value(test, 4)
                ]
        tables.append(array)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import_excel(table)
    print(" Input: \n")
    for i in tables:
        # pass
        print(i)

print("\n Output:")
num1 = tables[0]
num2 = tables[1]
num3 = tables[2]
num4 = tables[3]
num5 = tables[4]

nu1 = 1
i = 1
while (nu1 < num2[i]):
    print("%d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d" % (nu1, num2[i], num3[i], num4[i], num5[i]))
    nu1 = nu1 + 1

# End of the program
```

**Output:**

```
> python demo.py
 Input: 

[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
[11.0, 22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 55.0]
[111.0, 222.0, 333.0, 444.0, 555.0]
[1111.0, 2222.0, 3333.0, 4444.0, 5555.0]
[11111.0, 22222.0, 33333.0, 44444.0, 55555.0]

 Output:
1        22      222     2222    22222
2        22      222     2222    22222
3        22      222     2222    22222
...
20       22      222     2222    22222
21       22      222     2222    22222
```

**Here is the variation in the program that avoids global variables and uses for loops to read data from the excel file:**

```
# File name:  demo.py
# 
# Input: test.xlsx
#        1  5   10  15  20
#        2  14  21  22  26
#        3  5   6   24  30
#        4  11  23  26  30


import xlrd
from xlrd import xldate_as_tuple
import datetime

# Function to import data fom the excel file
def import_excel():

    # Open the file
    data = xlrd.open_workbook(r'D:\\test.xlsx')

    # Open the sheet 0
    sheet = data.sheets()[0]

    # Get values of all cells in the sheet
    table = []
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        array = []
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            array.append(sheet.cell_value(row, col))
        table.append(array)

    # Return table data
    # Using the return statement in function avoids the need for global variables
    return table


# Main program begins here

table = import_excel()
print(" Input: \n")
for i in table:
    print(i)


print("\n Output:")
row = table[0]
# row = tables[1]
# row = tables[2]
# row = tables[3]
# row = tables[4]

n = 1
while (n <= row[1]):
    print("%d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d" % (n, row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]))
    n += 1

# End of program
```

**Output:**

```
> python demo.py

 Input:

[1.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0]
[2.0, 14.0, 21.0, 22.0, 26.0]
[3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 24.0, 30.0]
[4.0, 11.0, 23.0, 26.0, 30.0]

 Output:
1        5       10      15      20
2        5       10      15      20
3        5       10      15      20
4        5       10      15      20
5        5       10      15      20
```

Comment: thanks very much, here is my test.xlsx data [1, 5, 10, 15, 20] i want output: [1, 5, 10, 15, 20]  [2, 5, 10, 15, 20]  [3, 5, 10, 15, 20]  [3, 5, 10, 15, 20] [4, 5, 10, 15, 20]  how shoud i write the code,thanks again, u r so kind

Comment: Hi DaMeilao, I updated the answer to suit this requirement. I also removed global variables and updated the import function to reduce the total number of lines of code.

Comment: omg ,i almost crying, wow, it works, amazing,that's what i want, thank you very much,you really awesome * v *

Answer (score 0):

Put while (nu1 < num2):
And check if you have declare the int in nu1 and num2.Hope this will help you out.

Comment: here is test.xlsx data:[2.0, 14.0, 21.0, 22.0, 26.0] [3.0, 5.0, 6.0, 24.0, 30.0] [4.0, 11.0, 23.0, 26.0, 30.0] [4.0, 14.0, 20.0, 28.0, 35.0]